# un sorted values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

```
BILLING_DATE          OOQ     AQ        SQ  BILLING_HOUR
26-06-2022             0      1       5       0
26-06-2022            22      25     02       8
26-06-2022            07      17     76       10

a=df.melt(['BILLING_DATE','BILLING_HOUR'],var_name='items',value_name=None).set_index(['BILLING_DATE','items','BILLING_HOUR']).squeeze().unstack().rename_axis(columns=None).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    BILLING_DATE    items   0   8   10
0   26-06-2022      AQ  1   25  17
1   26-06-2022      OOQ 0   22  07
2   26-06-2022      SQ  07  17  76
```

but i want:

```
    BILLING_DATE    items   0   8   10
0   26-06-2022      OOQ 0   22  0
1   26-06-2022      AQ  1   25  17
2   26-06-2022      SQ  5   02  76
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort based on the original order of the columns:

```
sorter = pd.Series({k:v for v,k in enumerate(df.columns)}).get

a = a.sort_values('items', key=sorter)
```

output:

```
  BILLING_DATE items  0   8  10
1   26-06-2022   OOQ  0  22   7
0   26-06-2022    AQ  1  25  17
2   26-06-2022    SQ  5   2  76
```